# how to determine which LUN my OnePlus 8Pro rom image files reside in?

Tags: linux-kernel, custom-rom, flashing, oneplus7

i am trying to flash my oneplus 8 pro using edl command in linux.

the format is as follows:

edl w gpt gpt.img --memory=ufs --lun=4

so with

fastboot getvar all

i can get the physical(?) address where the various image files reside:

```
(bootloader) parallel-download-flash:yes
(bootloader) hw-revision:20001
(bootloader) unlocked:no
(bootloader) off-mode-charge:1
(bootloader) charger-screen-enabled:1
(bootloader) battery-soc-ok:no
(bootloader) battery-voltage:3403
(bootloader) version-baseband:
(bootloader) version-bootloader:
(bootloader) erase-block-size: 0x1000
(bootloader) logical-block-size: 0x1000
(bootloader) variant:SM8 UFS
(bootloader) partition-type:mdm1m9kefsc:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdm1m9kefsc: 0x1000
(bootloader) partition-type:mdm1m9kefs2:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdm1m9kefs2: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:mdm1m9kefs1:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdm1m9kefs1: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:mdm1m9kefs3:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdm1m9kefs3: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:fsc:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:fsc: 0x20000
(bootloader) partition-type:fsg:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:fsg: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:modemst2:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:modemst2: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:modemst1:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:modemst1: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:ALIGN_TO_128K_2:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:ALIGN_TO_128K_2: 0x1A000
(bootloader) partition-type:storsec_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:storsec_b: 0x20000
(bootloader) partition-type:reserve4:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:reserve4: 0xFD0000
(bootloader) partition-type:reserve3:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:reserve3: 0xFD0000
(bootloader) partition-type:reserve2:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:reserve2: 0xFD0000
(bootloader) partition-type:reserve1:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:reserve1: 0x7E8000
(bootloader) partition-type:hyp_log:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:hyp_log: 0xFD0000
(bootloader) partition-type:qsee_log:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:qsee_log: 0xFD0000
(bootloader) partition-type:android_log:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:android_log: 0xFD0000
(bootloader) partition-type:kernel_log:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:kernel_log: 0xFD0000
(bootloader) partition-type:abl_log:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:abl_log: 0xFD0000
(bootloader) partition-type:op1:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:op1: 0x12C00000
(bootloader) partition-type:aging_mod:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:aging_mod: 0x2000000
(bootloader) partition-type:aging_kernel:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:aging_kernel: 0x4000000
(bootloader) partition-type:mdm1oemnvbktmp:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdm1oemnvbktmp: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:vm-data:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:vm-data: 0x400000
(bootloader) partition-type:vm-keystore:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:vm-keystore: 0x20000
(bootloader) partition-type:secdata:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:secdata: 0x7000
(bootloader) partition-type:uefivarstore:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:uefivarstore: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:storsec_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:storsec_a: 0x20000
(bootloader) partition-type:logdump:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:logdump: 0x4000000
(bootloader) partition-type:logfs:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:logfs: 0x800000
(bootloader) partition-type:limits-cdsp:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:limits-cdsp: 0x1000
(bootloader) partition-type:limits:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:limits: 0x1000
(bootloader) partition-type:spunvm:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:spunvm: 0x2000000
(bootloader) partition-type:msadp:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:msadp: 0x40000
(bootloader) partition-type:apdp:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:apdp: 0x40000
(bootloader) partition-type:dip:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:dip: 0x100000
(bootloader) partition-type:devinfo:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:devinfo: 0x1000
(bootloader) partition-type:logo_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:logo_b: 0x1000000
(bootloader) partition-type:imagefv_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:imagefv_b: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:featenabler_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:featenabler_b: 0x20000
(bootloader) partition-type:vm-linux_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:vm-linux_b: 0x2000000
(bootloader) partition-type:multiimgqti_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:multiimgqti_b: 0x8000
(bootloader) partition-type:multiimgoem_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:multiimgoem_b: 0x8000
(bootloader) partition-type:uefisecapp_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:uefisecapp_b: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:dtbo_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:dtbo_b: 0x1800000
(bootloader) partition-type:vbmeta_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:vbmeta_b: 0x10000
(bootloader) partition-type:qupfw_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:qupfw_b: 0x14000
(bootloader) partition-type:devcfg_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:devcfg_b: 0x20000
(bootloader) partition-type:cmnlib64_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:cmnlib64_b: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:cmnlib_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:cmnlib_b: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:boot_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:boot_b: 0x6000000
(bootloader) partition-type:keymaster_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:keymaster_b: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:dsp_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:dsp_b: 0x4000000
(bootloader) partition-type:abl_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:abl_b: 0x800000
(bootloader) partition-type:mdtp_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdtp_b: 0x2000000
(bootloader) partition-type:mdtpsecapp_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdtpsecapp_b: 0x400000
(bootloader) partition-type:bluetooth_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:bluetooth_b: 0x100000
(bootloader) partition-type:modem_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:modem_b: 0x20000000
(bootloader) partition-type:hyp_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:hyp_b: 0x800000
(bootloader) partition-type:tz_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:tz_b: 0x400000
(bootloader) partition-type:aop_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:aop_b: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:logo_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:logo_a: 0x1000000
(bootloader) partition-type:imagefv_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:imagefv_a: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:featenabler_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:featenabler_a: 0x20000
(bootloader) partition-type:vm-linux_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:vm-linux_a: 0x2000000
(bootloader) partition-type:multiimgqti_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:multiimgqti_a: 0x8000
(bootloader) partition-type:multiimgoem_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:multiimgoem_a: 0x8000
(bootloader) partition-type:uefisecapp_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:uefisecapp_a: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:dtbo_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:dtbo_a: 0x1800000
(bootloader) partition-type:vbmeta_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:vbmeta_a: 0x10000
(bootloader) partition-type:qupfw_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:qupfw_a: 0x14000
(bootloader) partition-type:devcfg_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:devcfg_a: 0x20000
(bootloader) partition-type:cmnlib64_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:cmnlib64_a: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:cmnlib_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:cmnlib_a: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:boot_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:boot_a: 0x6000000
(bootloader) partition-type:keymaster_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:keymaster_a: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:dsp_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:dsp_a: 0x4000000
(bootloader) partition-type:abl_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:abl_a: 0x800000
(bootloader) partition-type:mdtp_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdtp_a: 0x2000000
(bootloader) partition-type:mdtpsecapp_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdtpsecapp_a: 0x400000
(bootloader) partition-type:bluetooth_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:bluetooth_a: 0x100000
(bootloader) partition-type:modem_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:modem_a: 0x20000000
(bootloader) partition-type:hyp_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:hyp_a: 0x800000
(bootloader) partition-type:tz_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:tz_a: 0x400000
(bootloader) partition-type:aop_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:aop_a: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:mdmddr:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdmddr: 0x100000
(bootloader) partition-type:ddr:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:ddr: 0x200000
(bootloader) partition-type:cdt:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:cdt: 0x20000
(bootloader) partition-type:ALIGN_TO_128K_1:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:ALIGN_TO_128K_1: 0x1A000
(bootloader) partition-type:xbl_config_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:xbl_config_b: 0x20000
(bootloader) partition-type:xbl_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:xbl_b: 0x500000
(bootloader) partition-type:xbl_config_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:xbl_config_a: 0x20000
(bootloader) partition-type:xbl_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:xbl_a: 0x500000
(bootloader) partition-type:userdata:f2fs
(bootloader) partition-size:userdata: 0x36F3453000
(bootloader) partition-type:rawdump:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:rawdump: 0x8000000
(bootloader) partition-type:vm-system_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:vm-system_b: 0x8000000
(bootloader) partition-type:vm-system_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:vm-system_a: 0x8000000
(bootloader) partition-type:metadata:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:metadata: 0x1000000
(bootloader) partition-type:vbmeta_system_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:vbmeta_system_b: 0x10000
(bootloader) partition-type:vbmeta_system_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:vbmeta_system_a: 0x10000
(bootloader) partition-type:recovery_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:recovery_b: 0x6400000
(bootloader) partition-type:recovery_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:recovery_a: 0x6400000
(bootloader) partition-type:super:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:super: 0x380000000
(bootloader) partition-type:opproduct_b:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:opproduct_b: 0x12C00000
(bootloader) partition-type:opproduct_a:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:opproduct_a: 0x12C00000
(bootloader) partition-type:config:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:config: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:op2:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:op2: 0x10000000
(bootloader) partition-type:modemdump:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:modemdump: 0x12C00000
(bootloader) partition-type:mdm_oem_stanvbk:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdm_oem_stanvbk: 0xA00000
(bootloader) partition-type:mdm_oem_dycnvbk:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:mdm_oem_dycnvbk: 0xA00000
(bootloader) partition-type:param:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:param: 0x100000
(bootloader) partition-type:frp:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:frp: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:keystore:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:keystore: 0x80000
(bootloader) partition-type:misc:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:misc: 0x100000
(bootloader) partition-type:persist:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:persist: 0x2000000
(bootloader) partition-type:ssd:raw
(bootloader) partition-size:ssd: 0x2000
(bootloader) has-slot:modem:yes
(bootloader) has-slot:system:no
(bootloader) current-slot:a
(bootloader) has-slot:boot:yes
(bootloader) slot-retry-count:b:0
(bootloader) slot-unbootable:b:no
(bootloader) slot-successful:b:no
(bootloader) slot-retry-count:a:6
(bootloader) slot-unbootable:a:yes
(bootloader) slot-successful:a:no
(bootloader) slot-count:2
(bootloader) secure:yes
(bootloader) serialno:ddef935c
(bootloader) product:kona
(bootloader) is-userspace:no
(bootloader) max-download-size:805306368
(bootloader) kernel:uefi
```

all:

but i need something like this, where the specific LUN can be matched to the corresponding .img file:

```
/dev/block/sdb -> LUN 1 - Boot LUN A

   pre: 24k 
/dev/block/sdb1  partition label="xbl_config_a" size_in_kb="512" type="5A325AE4-4276-B66D-0ADD-3494DF27706A" bootable="false" readonly="true" filename="xbl_config.img" 

/dev/block/sdb2  partition label="xbl_a" size_in_kb="7168" type="DEA0BA2C-CBDD-4805-B4F9-F428251C3E98" bootable="false" readonly="true" filename="xbl.img"    

partition label="last_parti" size_in_kb="0" type="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" bootable="false" readonly="true" filename=""
```

it seems that i have to access kernel device structure in order to view it. how do i do it?

Comment: While many might consider this totally readable, I have a dissenting opinion.

Comment: I formatted it, but I'm not sure I increased its literary value.

Comment: yeah the spirit of camaraderie